# Initial question on submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

So I have a trouble trying to solve the following problem: is it true that every $k$-dimensional submanifold $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a set of solutions of system of $(n-k)$ equations $f_i(x^1,...,x^n)=0$ for which rank of matrix $(\frac{\partial{f_i}}{\partial{x^j}}(a))$ where $i=1,...n-k$ and $j=1,...n$ is equal to $n-k$ at every point $a \in M$
I guess the answer is no, so I need to provide an example but I can’t construct it. 
Also the type of definition of submanifold which I’m using implies that submanifold is closed

Comment: It is true locally, but not necessarily globally.

Comment: So I need an example) could you give me a hint?

Comment: What about the Klein bottle in $\Bbb R^4$?